# Close colorPicker via Photoshop SDK

Tags: photoshop

I'm working with Photoshop SDK with Javascript, and I'm completely stuck on the color Picker behavior. 
I would close the Photoshop ColorPicker if open (I use `app.showColorPicker()` to present it).

Is there a way to close it from script ?

Comment: The color picker changes the `app.foregroundColor` property. If you have any specific questions about how to use it in your script let me know. If you provide a sample of your script I could probably help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to do this in the script or if it's even necessary. Just from testing out `app.showColorPicker()` it appears that the script hangs and waits for the user to either pick a color and click ok, or click cancel (both of which close the window) before continuing with script so it would close itself before evaluating the next line of code anyway.